# open failed: EISDIR(is a directory)

Tags: java, android, file, dropbox, java-io

I try to upload a folder to Dropbox in my android code by this code:

```
try {
            // Upload to Dropbox
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            dbxClient.files().uploadBuilder("/" + file.getName()) //Path in the user's Dropbox to save the file.
                    .withMode(WriteMode.OVERWRITE) //always overwrite existing file
                    .uploadAndFinish(inputStream);
            Log.d("Upload Status", "Success");
        } catch (DbxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It works correct when 'file' is a directory. But when it is a folder, I will get this exception for the first line:

```
open failed: EISDIR(is a directory)
```

Can I fix this problem? Or it must be a directory?

Comment: It *is* a directory, and that's the *problem.* You can't open directories as regular files.

Comment: The code is *not* correct when you pass a directory to it, and *that is why you are getting this exception.* All your futile edits notwithstanding.

Comment: @EJP So what should I do now? I must zip the file and pass the directory? Or there is a better way?

Comment: I suggest you fix your question so it reflects reality first. At present it is just a farrago of nonsense. Specifically, the last sentence, over which you have slaved so pointlessly, is self-evidently incorrect.